# Loop output is printed exponentially

Tags: python, python-3.x

When  i am building a for loop to print numbers of **n^2+n+41**  where n varies from 1 to 100, I am seeing the output repeated several times for each number, with each number outputting more times than before.

```
k=0
for i in range(101):
    i, (i**2 + i + 41)
    for p in range(2,(i**2 + i + 41)//2+1):
        if((i**2 + i + 41)%p==0):
            k=k+1
        if(k<=0):
            print((i**2 + i + 41), " is prime")
        else:
            print((i**2 + i + 41), "isn't prime")
```

What am I doing wrong here? Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Seems this is not a runnable code? Fix it first please.

Comment: Your code is hard to follow with all the repeated `(i**2 + i + 41)`. I would suggest storing that calculation to some variable like `num = (i**2 + i + 41)`. And the reason it outputs more is because you have a nested for loop which runs from 2 up to half of that num value for each value of i.

Comment: Your first `for` loop is iterating in the range [0, 101[ when it should be (as you said) [1-100], use `range(1,101)` instead of `range(101)`

Comment: @H.Tacon Dat `[0, 101[` notation tho

Comment: @MateenUlhaq that's a mathemathical notation, `[0, 101[` means under limit close upper limit open (I don't know if that was a critic, cause english isn't my mother language, so I'm explaining it anyways ¯\_(ツ)_/¯)

Comment: @H.Tacon It's fine, though I usually see `[0, 101)` which was why I was teasing. :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your conditionals should be external to the inner for loop:

```
k=0
for i in range(1, 101):
    i, (i**2 + i + 41)
    for p in range(2,(i**2 + i + 41)//2+1):
        if((i**2 + i + 41)%p==0):
            k=k+1
    if(k<=0):
        print((i**2 + i + 41), " is prime")
    else:
        print((i**2 + i + 41), "isn't prime")
```

Added the loop correction that I mentioned in the comment too

You could improve this test to verify if the number is prime too, besides that is another question, in your case (check primes under 100) that wouldn't make a big difference.